# A portnumber I changed in XAMPP interferes my sites URL on my webhosts server

Tags: wordpress, apache, xampp, port, httpd.conf

I developed a Wordpress website using XAMPP envionment.

When I installed XAMPP I had to change XAMPP Apache servers port number in httpd.conf file from 80 to 8080 (because of some overlaping reasons). Now when the site is done I uploaded it to my webhosts server. I tranfered the files, imported database, fixed the wp_config file, installed CMS and everythin went ok. Site should be ok and redy to view via browser. For somehow the port I changed in XAMPP now interferes the sites URL in my webhosts server.

The URL to view the site in webhosts server is:
mydomain.fi.www33.web-host-server.fi

My browser for some reason tries to enter to this URL:
mydomain.fi.www33.web-host-server.fi:8080

I tried to change my sites frontpage URL from database via phpMyAdmin
(for example http://localhost:8080/mydomain/public_html/?page_id=126
to
http://www.mydomain.fi/?page_id=126) but It didn't work.

For point of reference when I upload a site that were in another webhosts server to my new webhosts server there is no problems.

Is there an explanation to why my webhost server doesn't coop with sites thet were developed localy in XAMPP?

Comment: Follow the official instructions on how to move WordPress to a new server: http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress#Changing_Your_Domain_Name_and_URLs

Comment: This isn't helpfull. I know how to move sites around and I know how to operate databases. What I need is the information how and why the port number affects the site and how to fix it.